# How to authenticate for Facebook graph API using standard OAuth 2.0 libraries?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

In a project I am using Authentication multiple times for different providers, so I am relying on standard libraries.

I want to establish connection with Facebook yet it provides not completely standard authorization.

To test the connection I am using [REST Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en) in Authorization part of it I place a key and secret and for

- `Authorize URL` I provide `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize`
- `Access token URL` - `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token`
- Request token URL I leave empty or fill it with `https://graph.facebook.com/`

And what I get bck looks like this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Expected 1 '.' in the input between the postcard and the payload",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 1
    }
}
```

So my question is how to get authenticated forming standard OAuth calls?

**EDIT**
For the moment (testing stage) I found that data can be retrieved using no standard authentication but `access_token` with appropriate values. Yet sending http request with api key and secret exposed in the request url can not be the right way of ding it.